# Javascript/Jquery object into String

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am struggling with something.
I need to compare two strings.

```
 $.get("/user", function(data) {
       $("#domain").html(data.userAuthentication.details.hd);
});
```

This function returns the user's domain in my HTML `<span id="domain"></span>`. 
But I need to compare it with JavaScript. But i cant "stringify" this object in a variable.

How can i do that?

Comment: you want to compare what with what?

Comment: use .toString()

Comment: #domain result with a random string. (for instance var mystryng = domain.com)

Comment: already try toString() not working

Comment: @RaphaelObadia any error with toString() ?

Comment: try to remove double quotes from this html and then try to compare.

Comment: just return me object or bunch of ()""=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a if statement

```
 $.get("/user", function(data) {

       var mystryng = 'domain.com';
       if(data.userAuthentication.details.hd == mystryng) {
      // your code here
       }
       $("#domain").html(data.userAuthentication.details.hd);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! javascript drive me crazy some times.

Comment: Completly worth my -2 reputations :D <3

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text in the span through the following

```
$("#domain").text()
```

Compare it with any js variable you have.